# How to solve "Could not find artifact com.ohadr:authentication-flows"?

Tags: java, maven, authentication-flows

I've tried a:
    **mvn clean install -DskipTests -DdownloadSources=true**
for building https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows.git
and I'm having:

> ...Failed to execute goal on project client: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.ohadr.auth-flows:client:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.ohadr:authentication-flows:jar:1.6.2-SNAPSHOT... The POM
>   for com.ohadr:authentication-flows:jar:1.6.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available...

Next, I tried adding this repository:

```
     <repository>
       <id>central-maven</id>
       <name>Central Maven</name>
       <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
     </repository>
```

as well as downloading the jar (http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/ohadr/authentication-flows/1.6.0-RELEASE/authentication-flows-1.6.2-RELEASE.jar) and installing it manually:

```
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.ohadr \
   -DartifactId=authentication-flows \
   -Dversion=1.6.2-SNAPSHOT \
   -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=authentication-flows-1.6.2-RELEASE.jar
```

Now I have:

> ...Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project client: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure:...impl/CustomCreateAccountEndpoint.java:[6,38] package
>   com.ohadr.auth_flows.endpoints does not exist

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try using the __1.6.1-RELEASE__ to get that package, __1.6.0-RELEASE__ doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: You are right, 1.6.1 is the one! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version (master branch) of the client-app depends on the "latest" version - the SNAPSHOT version - of `authentication-flows` JAR. SNAPSHOTs do not exist in maven-repository, and this is why you get the error.

You can either clone authentication-flows project as well and build it locally, or change the dependency in 
the client-pom to version 1.6.1-RELEASE.

HTH

Comment: thanks, I've updated the pom here: https://github.com/ggmartins/Authentication-Flows/blob/master/client/pom.xml